# duvida com modal e javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal

tenho essa modal:

```
<div class="uk-modal" id="modalbaixados">
<div class="uk-modal-dialog">
    <div class="uk-form-row">
        <div class="uk-grid">

            <div><h3 class="heading_a"> Baixas parciais do lançamento selecionado</h3></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="uk-width-medium-2-10">
    <!--botão fechar modal-->
    <a class="md-btn md-btn-danger md-btn-wave-light md-btn-small uk-modal-close" bg>Fechar</a>
</div>
```

para abrir a modal:

```
<a href="#modalbaixados" data-uk-modal="{ center:true, bgclose:true }">
```

isso funciona perfeitamente, porem eu vou precisar abrir a modal a partir de uma função javascript, entao nessa função eu preciso de um codigo para abrir a modal:

```
 //abrir modal
$scope.abrirModal = function (conta) {       
    como abrir a modal?
}
```

vou precisar tb fechar essa modal por uma função:

```
//fechar modal
$scope.fecharModal = function () {       
    como fechar a modal?
}
```

como fazer isso ?

Comment: Já testaste o exemplo da documentação?
 https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/modal.html#javascript

Comment: `$('.modalSelector').on({

    'show.uk.modal': function(){
        console.log("Modal is visible.");
    },

    'hide.uk.modal': function(){
        console.log("Element is not visible.");
    }
});` - 

esse `.modalSelector` seria o que ? o id do modal ?